# Formatting display of of `set -v` output

Tags: bash, set

From the description of `set` in the `bash` `man` page:

```
-v   Print shell input lines as they are read.
```

Thus, the following example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# setv.sh
set -v
foo=bar
echo $foo
```

Generates output:

```
foo=bar
echo $foo
bar
```

Is there a way for it to prepend some string, say "+ " to each line, so as to clearly indicate which line is a line from the script, and which line is output of a line of from the script. Using the above example, the desired output would be:

```
+ foo=bar
+ echo $foo
bar
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "The output looks like"? What command did you execute to generate that undesirable output?

Comment: I think I now understand what you are looking for. I'll try to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get that kind of output you could use [`$BASH_COMMAND`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables) e.g. add

```
trap 'printf "%s %s\n" + "$BASH_COMMAND" >&2' DEBUG
```

instead of `set -x/v` at the top your script.

Comment: You would probably want to print that on stderr. The OP might also want `set -o functrace`