# Merge set x (xtrace) and v (verbose)

Tags: shell, configuration, ash

How to merge `set -x` and `set -v` in `ash`? (or `set -v` with a prefix)

In other words, echo back command upon running.

The `DEBUG` signal does not exist in `ash`: `DEBUG: invalid signal specification`.

**`set -x`**

```bash
$ echo > foo.txt # Normal
$ set -x
$ echo > foo.txt # Example
+ echo
$ # Missing "> foo.txt # Example"
```

**`set -v`**

```bash
$ echo > foo.txt # Normal
$ set -v
$ echo > foo.txt # Example
echo > foo.txt # Example
$ # Missing prefix "> "
```

**`set -xv`**

```bash
$ echo > foo.txt # Normal
$ set -vx
$ echo > foo.txt # Example
echo > foo.txt # Example
+ echo
$ # Now there are two problems... (missing "> foo.txt  # Example" and missing prefix "> ")
```

**Desired**

```bash
$ echo > foo.txt # Normal
$ magic_command "> "
$ echo > foo.txt # Example
> echo > foo.txt # Example
$ ls
> ls
foo.txt
```

Comment: @muru, I've reopened as the dup ([Formatting display of of \`set -v\` output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/430480)) is about bash where the answer uses the DEBUG trap, and the OP is clearly aware that the DEBUG trap can't be used here

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas sure, the original post didn't mention ash at all and was tagged bash. I guess OP wasn't aware which shell they were using at the time.